# Game rejected by Google due to Singular SDK

Tags: unity-game-engine, google-play, unityads

I just send a new version of my game but this message from Google

> Your app is using the Singular SDK which collects but may not be limited to Android ID and Advertising ID identifiers. Persistent device identifiers may not be linked to other personal and sensitive user data or resettable device identifiers.

> You may consider moving to another SDK; removing this SDK; or if available from your SDK provider, upgrading to a policy-compliant version of this SDK that does not include the violating code.

> According to the information provided by your SDK provider, you may consider upgrading to 12.0.5. Please consult the SDK provider for further information.

> Affected Version(s):
> App Bundle:37, App Bundle:37

We use unity ads, we have the latest version of `unity ads 4.3.0` but we don't know where we can find this Singular SDK to update it.
No trace of it in our game, never used, and never heard about it.

Please how could we correct it ?

Comment: Questions about _compliance_ and/or _legality_ are always best served by contacting the vendor directly and/or legal professionals rather than seeking help from the Internet.  Good luck!

Comment: @MickyD you are right, but i contacted Play store but don't get an answer. And the idea is also to share the answer in case someone face the same issue.

Comment: _"And the idea is also to share the answer in case someone face the same issue"_ - whilst a noble idea, _sharing_ compliancy and/or legality advice on the Internet is just as inadvisable.  Try contacting Tech Support maybe?

Comment: Are you sure you are using only Unity Ads? No other SDK that involves a third party that collects data from your game?

Comment: @Yugerten yes, only Unity Ads

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is something called `Mediation Ads`, installed automatically. From the package Manager, remove this package and delete the `MediationDependecies.xml` file. You will get rid of duplications errors. Search in the folder `Singular SDK`, delete them all, build and re upload your apk.

Mediation deletetion remove errors or `duplicate class com.unity3d.ads.buildconfig found in modules classes.jar...`